# Azure Databricks Missing entries when streaming to SQL Datawarehouse

Tags: spark-streaming, databricks, azure-synapse

first I had following instructions, and when upload 20.000 files I got 20.000 records in the DB (Each file only holds 1 rec).

```
aTracking = sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true', delimiter=';').schema(csvSchema).load("wasbs://" + blobContainer + "@" + blobStorage + ".blob.core.windows.net/rtT*.csv")

aTracking.write \
    .option('user', dwUser) \
    .option('password', dwPass) \
    .jdbc('jdbc:sqlserver://' + dwServer + ':' + dwJdbcPort + ';database=' + dwDatabase, 'stg_tr_energy_xmlin.csv_in', mode = 'append' )
```

Then, for speed purposes I thought would be better to stream with Polybase ... Coded as ... But there I only got +- 17.000 entries.

```
aTracking = spark.readStream.format('csv').options(header='true', delimiter=';').schema(csvSchema).load("wasbs://" + blobContainer + "@" + blobStorage + ".blob.core.windows.net/rtT*.csv")

aTracking.writeStream \
         .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
         .option("url", sqlDwUrl) \
         .option("tempDir", "wasbs://uploaddw@" + blobStorage + ".blob.core.windows.net/stream") \
         .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
         .option("dbTable", "stg_tr_energy_xmlin.csv_in") \
         .option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint") \
         .start()
```

Any suggestions what could cause this ?

Comment: The first step would be to ascertain which ones are missing and try to discern a pattern

Comment: Found out what happened. Obviously the system reminds what files have been treated already. In a first run i did only opload 3000 files; restarted streaming, tuncated table and uploaded 20.000 files. +-3000 with the same name ...

Comment: Anybody has a idea where this is kept, the 'list' of streamed files ? Would be usefull to delete them afterswards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of your structured streaming query is tracked in the checkpoint location. "Every streaming source is assumed to have offsets (similar to Kafka offsets (...)) to track the read position in the stream. The engine uses checkpointing and write ahead logs to record the offset range of the data being processed in each trigger". See the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) (search for checkpointing) for more details.

So if you want to reprocess all your files delete the checkpoint location dir (or define a new one) defined under:

```
.option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint").
```

Additionally _spark_metadata file in the target dir is checked, so if you want all data to be written again, you should also cleanup the target dir (with Azure SQL Data Warehouse the temp dir).